# Why is audio time 4sec?

Tags: javascript

```
const startAudioBtn = document.getElementById("startAudioBtn");
const audio = document.getElementById("previewAudio");
let stream;
let recorder;
let audioFile;
let controlTimer = null;
const init = async () => {
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: false,
    audio: true,
  });
  audio.srcObject = stream;
  audio.play();
};
init();
const handleStart = (event) => {
  startAudioBtn.removeEventListener("click", handleStart);
  startAudioBtn.addEventListener("click", handleStop);
  startAudioBtn.innerText = "Stop Recording";
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    audioFile = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
    audio.srcObject = null;
    audio.src = audioFile;
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
  };
  recorder.start();
  controlTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    handleStop();
  }, 5000);
};
const handleStop = (event) => {
  startAudioBtn.removeEventListener("click", handleStop);
  startAudioBtn.addEventListener("click", handleDownload);
  startAudioBtn.innerText = "Download Recording";
  if (controlTimer) {
    clearTimeout(controlTimer);
    controlTimer = null;
  }
  recorder.stop();
};
const handleDownload = (event) => {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = audioFile;
  a.download = "My Audio.webm";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
};
startAudioBtn.addEventListener("click", handleStart);
```

i wrote this code, expecting audio time will be limited in 5sec but the recorded audio time
is 4sec...what is the problem..?

i changed the setTimeout time 5000 -> 6000 and then it worked. But i wonder why.

Comment: Maybe that is the time it takes to load the file. Try setting the timer right before starting the audio play.

Comment: Is the recorded file exactly 4000ms or rounds to 4 seconds?

Comment: I think it is rounded value..